# Creating a fixture list using a mathematic approach

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, math

I have been doing some research and looked at this maths technique of a polygon algorithm to help create fixtures for a five a side league. I would like this to be implemented using hopefully a set base technique. What I acquire just for now is a fixture list to be created for a five a side league with the following requirements:

- There are 3 leagues with 5 teams per league
- Each team plays each other home and away within their own league
- Each set of games is played within a round/week (example of round and matches displayed in the URL)

I've set all the teams and the leagues, just require help of the fixtures and previously I used UNION and a CROSS JOIN between 'Team' table and 'Team' Table (to determine home and away teams) but now I want to start from scratch using this algorithm. I don't want to use nested loops, I think it can be done via set base but just require a more experience developer to see how they would do it and I believe this algorithm can help.

Here is the link of the algorithm: http://www.mathscareers.org.uk/article/football-fixtures-whats-score/

Thee schema for the league, team and fixture table is as follows:

League:

```
[LeagueID] TINYINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
    [LeagueName] VARCHAR(30) UNIQUE
```

Team:

```
[TeamID] TINYINT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
[TeamAbbreviation] CHAR(3) UNIQUE, 
[TeamName] VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE, 
[LeagueID] TINYINT CONSTRAINT FK_Team_League FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES League(LeagueID)
```

Fixture:

```
[FixtureID] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[WeekNumber] INT NOT NULL,
[FixtureDate] DATE NULL,
[HomeTeamID] TINYINT NULL,
[AwayTeamID] TINYINT NULL,
[LeagueID] TINYINT CONSTRAINT FK_Fixture_League FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES League(LeagueID)
```

Hope that helps, below is an existing piece of code/logic I used that failed if you want any reference (this failed because it did week 1- 11 for all team's home games, meaning a team's reverse fixtures when they were away were never correct as they will play games in the same week as their home games). That's why I want to change the logic to follow that polygon algorithm but don't know how to apply it with code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Fixture_Insert]
@StartFixtureWeek DATE

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN

INSERT INTO dbo.Fixture (WeekNumber, HomeTeamID, AwayTeamID, FixtureDate, LeagueID)
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY h.teamID ORDER BY h.TeamID, a.TeamID, h.LeagueID) AS WeekNumber,
    h.TeamID,
    a.TeamID,
    DATEADD(day,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY h.LeagueID)-1)*7,@StartFixtureWeek) AS FixtureWeek, 
    h.LeagueID
FROM dbo.Team h
CROSS JOIN dbo.Team a
WHERE h.TeamID <> a.TeamID
AND h.LeagueID = a.LeagueID

END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets us translate the algorithm, called [round robin scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm), in terms of an ordered list `l` of N teams (which correspond to N-1 polygon vertices + the polygon center):

- `l` defines fixtures by playing the first team from the list against the last, the second against the first before last, etc.
  That is, for `0 ≤ x < N`, you play team `l[x]` vs team `l[N-1-x]`.
- To generate the next set of fixtures, you rotate the `N-1` first elements of the list.
  That is `l = l[1] + l[2] + ... + l[N-2] + l[0] + l[N-1]`
- Once you've done the full set of `N-1` rotations, do it again but swapping home and away teams: play team `l[N-1-x]` vs team `l[x]` instead of the opposite.

If you start with the numerically ordered list `0..N-1` then at round `i` the list is:
`l = [(i + 0) % (N-1)] +  [(i + 1) % (N-1)] + ... +  [(i + N-2) % (N-1)] + [N-1]`

That is, **fixtures are at round `i`:**

- **`i` vs `N-1`**
- For `0 < x < (N-1) / 2`, **`(x + i) % (N-1)` vs `(N-1 - x + i) % (N-1)`**

Now there is a trick, as this **only works for even numbers.** Otherwise the last team always plays (against team `i` at round `i`) whereas naturally each round has one team that can't play. That would mean team 4 plays one more game than the other teams.

To solve this, we **add a dummy team,** so for 5 teams we have `N = 6`, and at round `i`:

- `i` vs `5` (the dummy team)
- `(i + 1) % 4` vs `(4 + i) % 4`
- `(i + 2) % 4` vs `(3 + i) % 4`

Now that you know this, you can generate a function that will give you fixtures based on round number. It should output the following:

> round 0: 0 rests, 1 vs 4, 2 vs 3
>   round 1: 1 rests, 2 vs 0, 3 vs 4
>   round 2: 2 rests, 3 vs 1, 4 vs 0
>   round 3: 3 rests, 4 vs 2, 0 vs 1
>   round 4: 4 rests, 0 vs 3, 1 vs 2

---

Note that instead of `i` in the formulas `x + i` and `N-1 - x + i` you can use any multiple `m * i` (so `x + m * i` and `N-1 - x + m * i`) as long as `m` and `N-1` and [relatively prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relatively_prime). Here `N - 1 = 5`  is prime, so you can use any `m` you want.

Comment: Thank you cimbali, that makes sense logically. The problem I am going to have is coding it so I wanted to know if you don't mind if we can go through it bit by bit (maybe using chat) so I can see and understand what to do?

Comment: Marked answer but have not coded it, as stated if you don't mind going through with me on how to code it, just drop me a comment. I will have SO active so I know what's happening

Comment: @carlBrooks I'm sorry I don't have a lot of time right now (plus I can't find you in chat). Try starting by writing a procedure that returns (or inserts) the fixtures for just one round, given the round number. You have all the formulas to do that.

Comment: Cool Cimbali, I managed to write it for home and away but the week numbers are not correct as it only displays week numbers correctly for each home team, it will reset when there is a new home team. Problem with that is if team is away, they may clash with their own home game. I used CROSS JOIN for it